# sign function inequality $ -a (S-S*) sgn (S-S*)< -a(S-S*) ?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How it is possible that $-a (S-S*) x \leq -a (S-S*) sgn (S-S*)? $. Note that $x \leq1$ and $a>0$.
Also $-a (S-S*) sgn (S-S*)\leq -a(S-S*)$ it is possible?
Any other possible is there?
$a$ and $S*$ are  positive constants. $S$ and $x$ are variables in the domain, and satisfy the condition $0<S ≤ 1, 0<x ≤ 1.$

Comment: Totally unclear... What is $x$ in $x \le 1$ ? What are $S$ and $S*$ ?

Comment: Please, fix the title: I think it must be $\le$ (as in the text).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: With $a > 0$ we have two cases : (i) $S$ is non-negative. In this case $-aS \text {sgn}(S)=-aS$. (ii) $S$ is negative. In this case $-aS \text {sgn}(S)=-(-aS)=aS$ and $aS <0$. But $-aS >0$.

Comment: a and S* are parameter positive constants. S and x are variables in the domain, and satisfy the condition 0<S ≤ 1, 0<x ≤ 1.

Comment: fix the values. kindly answer the edited question.